# DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping for portlets vs. servlets

Tags: spring-mvc

I have been developing with Spring MVC in a Servlet environment for quite some time, mostly on Spring 3.1.x and 3.2.x, but recently moved jobs to a company that uses a mixture of Portlets and Servlets using Spring 3.0.6.

Fist, there seems to be two versions of DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping, one for [Portlets](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html) and one for [Servlets](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html).  My limited knowledge of Portlets makes me believe they are just an extention of Servlets, so I can vaguely understand the need to have two separate HandlerMappings, one to handle generic Servlets, the other to handle specifics to Portlest.  What is throwing me is how they each seems to behave differently with regaurds to how they handle the @RequestMapping annotations, and how my new employer has chosen to set things up.

In my past, I have had one DispatchHandler for the entire application.  I know you can have multiple DispatchHandlers, but I never saw the benefit past segregation of sub-context XMLs.  Anyhow, in the past I would have a DispatchHandler mapped to "/", and then each Controller set a mapping on top using @RequestMapping("/someUrl") and then another @RequestMapping on each handler method further extending the URL mapping.  So, from a browser I would get something like:

> http://somehost.com/myWar/myController/myMethod

where the first "/myWar" is mapped to the WAR deployment, the next "/" is mapped to the DispatchServlet, "/myController" is the Controller's mapping, and anything after is matched to some method using a combination of URL signature, request method, parameters, etc.

Now lets evaluate what I am seeing at my new firm.  First, each Controller gets its own DispatchServlet, so there is like 20-30 DispatchServlets defined, all with different base URIs mapped, some with the same base Application Context XML, some with different ones, all using the same Application Context from the ContextLoaderListener.  Each of the subsequent DispatchServlet's path is the same as the @RequestMapping on their "mapped" Controller, so in the above example DispatchServlet would have the path "/myController" and the Controller would have @RequestMapping("/myController").  On top of that, at the Controller's method level, the value specified on @RequestMapping seems to totally ignore any additional pathing applied to it.

So, for instance, if I have a Controller with @RequestMapping("/myController"), followed by a method with @RequestMapping("/edit"), hitting the URL http://somehost.com/myWar/myContoller/edit gives me a 404.  However, if I change the method-level @RequestMapping to @RequestMapping(parameter="actionMethod=edit"), and the URL to http://somehost.com/myWar/myController?actionMethod=edit, it maps just fine and I get my page.  Further, if I change my method-level @RequestMapping to @RequestMapping(value="/edit",params="actionMethod=view") neither http://somehost.com/myWar/myController?actionMethod=edit nor http://somehost.com/myWar/myController/edit?actionMethod=edit work at all.  The problem is that now to get to anything besides the default mapping at the method level requires me to take on "?actionMethod=edit", instead of simply extending the URI with the added paths.  Also, it prevents me from using a RESTful approach, since now I can't define something like @RequestMapping("/somePath/{id}").

I have so much confussion in my brain, like why is the DispatchServlet mapping in the web.xml overlapping the Controllers @RequestMapping, and why is the @RequestMapping at the Controller's method level not working when I set the value property to a valid URI mapping, but works fine when I set some parameter mapping?

Oh, and sorry for the long posting.  I just want to get a better understanding of what is happening here so I can either deal with it with an intellegent approach, or go back to my new group and say "this should be changed, and this is why".  I can extend this lengthy question with some simplified code examples if that helps.